# Magento Order Set to Processing but no payment received

Tags: php, magento, paypal, payment-gateway, worldpay

We have a Magento website that processes payments using Worldpay and Paypal payment gateways. Both are using the redirect method to process payments. Yesterday a user attempted to make two orders which were both abandoned and then a third order was placed which was set to 'processing' within the admin area but there was no payment received for the order.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue to this or is this theoretically possible within Magento? I have never witnessed this occurring before so am a little concerned that it may be some sort of exploit. We followed up with the customer and the telephone conversation all seemed a little shady..

Thanks!

Comment: hi did you ever resolve this behaviour?